# Rank 2 in National Ph.D. Entrance Exam vs. Rank 2 in the National Ph.D. Entrance Exam

Tags: definite-articles

Is this grammatical? I want to put it in my resume but I'm not sure whether it is grammatical and natural or not.

> Rank 2 in National Ph.D. Entrance Exam 2015
>
> Top Student in M.A. Program (GPA: 18.69)
>
> Rank 3 in National M.A. Entrance Exam 2013
>
> Third Student in B.A. Program (GPA: 17.53)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a list of accomplishments, ordinal numbers are normally used to indicate rank.  (Replace instance's of SCHOOLNAME with the correct college/university.)

> Second in 2015 National Ph.D. Entrance Exam
>   First in SCHOOLNAME's M.A. Program (GPA: 18.69)
>   Third in 2013 National M.A. Entrance Exam
>   Third in SCHOOLNAME's B.A. Program (GPA: 17.53)

Also, depending on where you're applying, you may need to reconfigure those GPA values.  For instance, an American company would expect a GPA to be between 0 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no, it isn't grammatical or natural to omit the article in formal writing.

If you're saying it, you'd say something like:

> I got the second rank in **the** National Ph.D. Entrance Exam 2015

That being said, it's not uncommon for resumes to have bullet points in what's called [Headlinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese), an abbreviated style of writing (like in newspaper headlines). This style omits articles (a/an/the).

I guess your missing articles in a resume won't come across as ungrammatical, especially in a bulleted list.